# charAt in java not working, first letter of word is not showing

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

hey guys my problem is the first letter of a word is not showing in my `ListView` but it shows a blank. how can i fix this . I believe my problem is in `charAt` .Sorry I am newbie

here is my code

```
  @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_View);

        holder.SubjectName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        holder.SubjectFullForm = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textviewFullForm);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    PlacesList subject = SubjectListTemp.get(position);

    holder.SubjectName.setText(subject.getSubName());

    holder.SubjectFullForm.setText(subject.getSubFullForm());

    String firstLetter = String.valueOf(getItem(position).charAt(0));

    ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL; // or use DEFAULT
    // generate random color
    int color = generator.getColor(getItem(position));

    TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder()
            .buildRound(firstLetter, color); // radius in px

    holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

    return convertView;

}
```

and this is my PlacesList.java

```
public class PlacesList {

String SubName = null;
String SubFullForm = null;

public PlacesList(String Sname, String SFullForm) {

    super();

    this.SubName = Sname;

    this.SubFullForm = SFullForm;
    }

 public String getSubName() {

    return SubName;

    }
 public void setSubName(String code) {

    this.SubName = code;

    }
 public String getSubFullForm() {

    return SubFullForm;

    }
 public void setSubFullForm(String name) {

    this.SubFullForm = name;

    }

 @Override
 public String toString() {

    return  SubName + " " + SubFullForm ;

    }

    public char[] charAt(int i) {
            return new char[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it a unicode string? do you have problem with other characters too(like `charat(2)`)?

Comment: im using this libray in my listview textdrawable https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable but my problem im not using <String> so the charat function is not working very well it show a blank on my listview instead of letter. im using <PlacesList> instead of <String>

Comment: is `PlacesList` a custom type? if yes, define a method that return the character at specific index like what you want.

Comment: yes. my problem is how can i define a method? Im newbie in android developing sorry.

Comment: i don't know how you defined your `PlaceList`. send the code and i'll tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type for `charAt` shouldn't be `char[]` but should be `char` since you are just returning a `char` at the position.

Also, what string are you getting the char from?  It should look something like this:

```
public char charAt(int i) {
    char[] array = yourString.toCharArray();
    return array[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right your `charAt` always returns blank. because it is a new char array and I am surprised that it does not throws `IndexOutOfBoundException` but anyway. you should have some `char[]` in your `PlacesList` and a constructor that gives it some value and then get the first character of that array.